# Moment.js - Duration within business/open/shift hours?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, duration

thanks in advance for your help. I am trying to calculate the duration between two dates with moment.js, but I can't figure out how to only count time (in our case minutes) when it is within our business/open hours.

Given these business hours:

- M-F from 8:00 AM to 6:00 PM
- Sa-Su from 10:00 AM to 2:00 PM

**simple duration example**

If a job starts Thu at 4:00 PM and ends Friday at 9:30 AM, then the duration is 210 minutes (4-6pm = 120 min, 8-9:30a = 90 min).

**less simple duration example**

If a job started Thu at 4:00 PM and ended Saturday at 9:30 AM, then duration is 720 minutes (4-6pm = 120 min, 8a-6p = 600 min, time between Fri 6p and Sat 10a does not add to duration)

Answer (score 0):

There is a library built on moment that is for this exact problem.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-time.
I believe something like the below example would work for you.

```
moment('2015-02-27T16:30:00Z').workingDiff(moment('2015-02-26T12:00:00Z'), 'hours');
// 12 
moment('2015-02-27T16:30:00Z').workingDiff(moment('2015-02-26T12:00:00Z'), 'hours', true);
// 12.5
```

Answer (score 0):

As Cruril pointed out, there is a library for dealing with this called [moment-business-time](https://github.com/lennym/moment-business-time/) and it is a plugin for [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

The problem is that you cannot run the plugin in the browser, because it is a Node package. I took the liberty of extracting out the script to avoid all the nasty requires logic. There is an open ticket for [building a client script](https://github.com/lennym/moment-business-time/issues/2) using [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

I documented the steps to build a client script [here](https://gist.github.com/rmkane/cafadd8855d221abd9d0bd19a9a61354), but the compiled script could still not find the `workingDiff` function. So I included a simplified; working version of moment-business-time in the script below.

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  workinghours: {
    0: null,                       // Sun : CLOSED
    1: [ '12:00:00', '20:00:00' ], // Mon : 8am - 4pm  (local EDT)
    2: [ '12:00:00', '18:00:00' ], // Tue : 8am - 2pm  (local EDT)
    3: [ '12:00:00', '20:00:00' ], // Wed : 8am - 4pm  (local EDT)
    4: [ '12:00:00', '18:00:00' ], // Thu : 8am - 2pm  (local EDT)
    5: [ '12:00:00', '16:00:00' ], // Fri : 8am - 12pm (local EDT)
    6: null                        // Sat : CLOSED
  },
  holidays : []
});

moment.locale('en');
moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York"); // Timezone plugin

var dateFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a';

// 0 + 8 + 6 + 8 + 6 + (4 - 1.5) + 0 = 30.5
var fromDate = moment('04/01/2018 00:00:00 am', dateFormat); // 2018-04-01T04:00:00.000Z
var toDate   = moment('04/06/2018 02:30:00 pm', dateFormat); // 2018-04-06T18:30:00.000Z

console.log(fromDate.workingDiff(toDate, 'hours'));       // 30 hours
console.log(fromDate.workingDiff(toDate, 'hours', true)); // 30.5 hours
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.16/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rmkane/32084550b349eaebe7e78e46903084ce/raw/434cf510165a65c234a8cb1cb99641bc7ab15c16/moment-business-time.js"></script>

<!--

https://github.com/lennym/moment-business-time
https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days#how-to-use

-->
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule - don't post a question without showing what you have currently. It's not looked kindly upon to ask for free work. Having said that - I also don't think just using a library to do it is necessarily the way to go if you are relatively green. You only get better by coding.

I wrote a quick unfinished proof to get minutes using moment. If this is for production code - don't use it, this is an example for you to look at and get one idea of how to approach a solution. (there are many).

Try looking over the code then writing your own implementation.

```js
function isOutOfTimeRange(time, start, end) {
  var date = time.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var startDate = date + ' ' + start;
  var endDate = date + ' ' + end;
  if (!time.isBetween(startDate, endDate, 'minute')) {
    var timeFormatted = time.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
    // If the time is exactly start or end time it should be ok to use
    if ((timeFormatted === startDate) || (timeFormatted === endDate)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isOutOfHours(time, businessHrs) {
  var day = time.day();
  var dayStart = businessHrs[day].start;
  var dayEnd = businessHrs[day].end;

  return isOutOfTimeRange(time, dayStart, dayEnd);
}

function getMinsWorked(startTime, endTime) {
  return moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime)).as('minutes');
}

function minutesWorked(startJob, endJob, bizHrs) {

  var start = moment(startJob);
  var end = moment(endJob);

  // return early if the start and end time range is invalid
  if (end.isBefore(start, 'second')) {
    return 'A job cannot start after it has ended!';
  }
  // return early if start or end is not within business hours
  if (isOutOfHours(start, bizHrs) || isOutOfHours(end, bizHrs)) {
    console.log('The start and end date must not be out of hours');
  }

  var timeDiff = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
  var firstDay = start.day();
  var lastDay = end.day();

  // return early if we can make a quick calculation on the same day
  if (firstDay === lastDay) {
    // create a duration object by diffing the end and start dates and return as minutes
    return timeDiff.as('minutes');
  }

  var totalMinsWorked = 0;
  var endTime;
  var startTime;

  for (var i = firstDay; i <= lastDay; ++i) {
    var currentDay = start.add(i - firstDay, 'days');
    var dateStr = currentDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var dayStart = moment(dateStr + ' ' + bizHrs[i].start);
    var dayEnd = moment(dateStr + ' ' + bizHrs[i].end);

    // it's the last day so diff the end time from the start
    if (i === lastDay) {
      totalMinsWorked += getMinsWorked(dayStart, end);
    }

    // it's the first day so go from the start time
    if (i === firstDay) {
      totalMinsWorked += getMinsWorked(start, dayEnd);
    }

    // its a centre day so just get the dif of the start to the end
    totalMinsWorked += getMinsWorked(dayStart, dayEnd);
  }
  return totalMinsWorked;
}

console.log(minutesWorked('2018-05-16 10:00', '2018-05-16 12:30', [{ // index 0 is Sunday
    start: '10:00',
    end: '14:00'
  },
  {
    start: '08:00',
    end: '18:00'
  },
  {
    start: '08:00',
    end: '18:00'
  },
  {
    start: '08:00',
    end: '18:00'
  },
  {
    start: '08:00',
    end: '18:00'
  },
  {
    start: '08:00',
    end: '18:00'
  },
  { // index 6 is Sat
    start: '10:00',
    end: '14:00'
  }
]));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code

```
var start = moment( "start date with time here" );
var end = moment( "end date with time here" );

var bizHours = {
    1: { start: "09:00", end: "18:00" },
    2: { start: "09:00", end: "18:00" },
    3: { start: "09:00", end: "18:00" },
    4: { start: "09:00", end: "18:00" },
    5: { start: "09:00", end: "17:00" },
    6: { },
    7: { }
};

var minutes = minutesWorked(start, end, bizHours);
console.log( minutes );



// calculation function
function minutesWorked(startJob, endJob, bizHrs) {
  if (end.isBefore(start, 'second')) {
    return 0;
  }

  var timeDiff = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
  var startDay = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var endDay = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var current = start;
  var currentDay = current.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  var totalMin = 0;
  var endTime, startTime;
  var weekday, bizStartTime, bizEndTime, duration;

  do {
    weekday = current.format('E');
    bizStartTime = bizHrs[weekday].start;
    bizEndTime = bizHrs[weekday].end;

    if ( bizStartTime && bizStartTime ) {
        if (currentDay == startDay) {
            startTime = start.format("HH:mm");
            startTime = startTime > bizStartTime ? startTime : bizStartTime;
            startTime = startTime < bizEndTime ? startTime : bizEndTime;
        } else {
            startTime = bizStartTime;
        }

        if (currentDay == endDay) {
            endTime = end.format("HH:mm");
            endTime = endTime < bizEndTime ? endTime : bizEndTime;
            endTime = endTime > bizStartTime ? endTime : bizStartTime;
        } else {
            endTime = bizEndTime;
        }

        startTime = moment(currentDay + ' ' + startTime);
        endTime = moment(currentDay + ' ' + endTime);

        duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime)).as('minutes');
        totalMin += duration;
    }

    // next day
    current.add(1, "days");
    currentDay = current.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }
  while (currentDay <= endDay);

  return totalMin;
}
```